# return url is not working on Live server vs development server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 Razor view which has a link that requires user login and its html is like this:

```
<a href="Home/Login?returnUrl=/myprojname/Product/Index">
```

and then an action method Login in homecontroller and a view. Which posts values to Logon action method.

inside the post action method I check if returnurl is not null then redirect to that URL. On local system it returns to this address

http://localhost:1235/myProjname/Product/Index

and works fine. But when I upload it to server (IIS 7), It returns to

http://domainname/myProjname/Product/Index

and gives 404 because there is no 'myProjname' there, If I remove the 'myprojname', it works with this url on live server

http://domainname/Product/Index

but for that I need to change href like this

```
<a href="Home/Login?returnUrl=/Product/Index">
```

In that case, It doesn't work with local system with URL

http://localhost:1235/Product/Index

Please suggest solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you serious?

Okay, we'll i'll play along.

The solution is to create links properly, not hard code them.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Home", new { returnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Product") })
```

On a side note, you probably don't need to pass `returnUrl` to the action. Pull it back from the `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` in the action method itself.

Not meaning to sound rude, but I **strongly** suggest you head over to http://www.asp.net/mvc and have a read/watch before proceeding any further.

Answer (score 1):

using `Url.Action` and `Url.Content` helper methods will generate URLs relative to the application root, and avoid these problems.

Also, `@Href("~/")` will generate the full path to the application root (from a view).